# Do I need to create the template if I want to load the template correctly?

Tags: django

```
def directory_index(path, fullpath):
    try:
        t = loader.select_template([
            'static/directory_index.html',
            'static/directory_index',
        ])
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        t = Engine(libraries={'i18n': 'django.templatetags.i18n'}).from_string(DEFAULT_DIRECTORY_INDEX_TEMPLATE)
        c = Context()
    else:
        c = {}
    files = []
    for f in fullpath.iterdir():
        if not f.name.startswith('.'):
            url = str(f.relative_to(fullpath))
            if f.is_dir():
                url += '/'
            files.append(url)
    c.update({
        'directory': path + '/',
        'file_list': files,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

This snippet is from static.py source code. It seems select_template will try to load directory_index.html or directory_index from the static subdirectory. To avoid raising the error, I guess I need to create a static folder following my DIR path and place directory_index.html in it, right?

Comment: Yes, you could create a custom `directory_index.html`. However, you shouldn't use Django to serve static files in production, therefore it's not clear why you would want to do that. You say *avoid raising the error*, but the Django code handles the error in the `except` block, therefore you won't see that error in your application.

Comment: @Alasdair, thanks for your help. I am just trying to figure out how the serve view works and I am reading the source code. Django is so hard for beginners.:(

Comment: There's a lot of code in Django, but you don't need to read/understand it all to get started - I've been using Django for 10 years and I don't think I've ever looked at the code behind `directory_index` until today. Hope it gets easier for you with time and practice :)

Comment: @Alasdair, thank you very much!